# User ID tracking before AND after login

Tags: google-analytics

Scenario:

1) Unregistered user visits site ("**clientID**" is generated by Google analytics)

2) Person registers ("**userID**" is generated by the site)

Now that this user has both clientID AND userID can you see the user's behaviour BEFORE the registration?

All of the articles I read such as:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en make a clear distinction between data BEFORE and AFTER registration, so is there a way to still see what a specific userID did BEFORE registering?

Basically I'm trying to track a given user's actions prior to registration as well as after the registration.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **custom dimension** at the **hit level** sent to Analytics with each interaction (pageviews and events).

When the user is not logged the value of custom dimension will be **loggedOut**, when the user is logged the custom dimensions becomes **loggedIn**.

In this way, i.e. with a custom report, you can view the user's navigation before and after the login.

Exact steps that outline how to mash the clientID and userID together: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/

Comment: thank you, I re-read the answer a few times, but just to clarify, this way I will be able to know what the registered user with a given userID did BEFORE he got assigned said userID (only when he/she had clientID) ?

Comment: For clarity, you must also send the userID as a custom dimension at user level. In this way you can surely get what you are looking for (for sessions since the user logged-in but not previous sessions if the user has never logged-in). To have those also, you need to send an additional custom dimension at the user level with the ClientID. Look at this here: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/

Comment: ok thank you for additional details, looks like exactly what i'm looking for. Wish this was made available inside the userID views, this forcible mishmash of fields seems very awkward